# Can this be a very simple cross cut sled with replaceable zero inserts?

Tags: sled

I am trying to reuse an older crosscut sled.
I will have problems with using the old cut for the blade so I googled for a solution and I came across a couple of complicated designs with replaceable zero inserts. Those would add another piece of plywood on top of the one that makes the sled base.

Since my fences are very solid (both front and back) I could practically cut out the piece of plywood 1" or 2" to the left and right of the blade cut and install a replacement screwed to the fence as shown below. Wood nuts will be installed int the fence and then I will use screws to attach a new insert every time I need a new one like below and then make a new cut. I wonder what I am missing since I never seen this simple design[image]

Comment: I can't see why your plan wouldn't work assuming the sled is strongly constructed throughout. It's really hard for anyone to to be sure and give reliable advice though without seeing the sled in the flesh and having a close look at how it's put together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work. This is how mine works. People like to make things very complicated... a lot of people like making jigs more than anything else.

Comment: This how big is the distance from the top of the fence to the top of the cut made by the blade in the fence in your case? There is a weak point there that might allow the fence to crack when handled of the table. Both fences will have to crack in order to damage the sled but I am just wondering if that might be problem

Comment: A valid point. I made my fences out of plywood, and doubled up the thickness and increased the height in the area around where the blade goes.

Comment: Same here but I don't have the hump that you see in some of the designs that are available on Internet

Comment: you don't need the hump... its a waste of wood really (because of the excess that you cut away). on mine, that doubled up piece IS the hump. glued and screwed on back.